# How to provide user defined argument and value in docker run?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to achieve something like
docker run   --delay=

I could provide the value for delay using ENTRYPOINT AND CMD without providing argument in docker run but could not find a way to do from docker run.

In short, I want to know how to pass user defined argument and value to docker run command or using dockerfile

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it using environment variable. There are two ways to set environment variable.

- In **Dockerfile** -> You can set as follows. Detailed Explanation at https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env

  `ENV <key> = <value>`
- In **docker run** command -> You can set using `-e` flag. Detailed Explanation at https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e-env-env-file

  `docker run -e <key> = <value> <image_name>`

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do that but I would recommend to go with [environment variables](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e-env-env-file). Just define the variable while running `docker run` and use it in your `ENTRYPOINT` script.

```
docker run -e DELAY=30 IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

Afterward use it in your `ENTRYPOINT` script as:

```
!#/bin/bash

# Play with $DELAY
echo $DELAY

# Start the root process
exec root_process_command
```

I hope it help!